# npm i fails with errors - unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, package.json, angular15

It's been a while as npm i fails to run, it produces the error.
Angular 15 used, and previously there were no errors. We don't use Angular 16 and it's unclear why it complains about 16.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree                          
npm ERR!                                                                     
npm ERR! While resolving: MYFJ@2.7.0-2                      
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.2.9                                         
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core                                          
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^15.2.8" from mylib@2.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/mylib
npm ERR!     mylib@"2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.9" from @angular/animations@15.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^15.2.8" from mylib@2.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/mylib
npm ERR!       mylib@"2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/cdk)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"16.0.4" from @angular/common@16.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"^15.2.8" from mylib@2.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/mylib
npm ERR!       mylib@"2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Any ideas where is a conflict come from and how to fix?

Comment: Please share your `package.json` file. It would appear that you have `@angular/common` set to 16.0.4, for example, and `@angular/animations` set to 15.2.9 but `@angular/core`  set to 15.2.8. Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and re-installing? Checking your Node version?

Comment: Please share **package.json** since it looks like some packages are Angular 16 and some packages are Angular 15. The code in package.json will help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove package.lock / yarn.lock / node_modules

npm i --force or npm i -f

To really solve it - review and update your node-modules.